# Is there a preprocessor software specifically meant for C language that helps us add complex programming language rules?

Tags: open-source, c

The limited features of the GCC preprocessor helps us control the versions of code easily along with giving macros and other stuff.

But is there a software out there (preferably open-source) that helps us define complex language rules, that later get "preprocessed" to the C language? The "powerful" preprocessor must be enough to let us define rules similar to the C++ language. This is just a random thought that occurred to me. So is there a software out there that does this?

Comment: Did you look at e.g. lex and yacc?

Comment: Certainly "early" versions of C++ were implemented as a pre-parser that generated C code that was then actually compiled - I am not 100% sure that this this is no longer the case.

Comment: I just had a hunch that this kind of software might exist. I wanted to use one if possible, just to play around with it!

Comment: You can probably use any `templating` system